# post data to PHP page in external server and load content from JavaScript in local computer

Tags: javascript, php, post

I want to post data to a PHP file in a server (www.domaine.com) using a JavaScript located in computer / mobile app

example : test.php

```
<?php
    $x = $_POST['count'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $x++)
        echo $x;
?>
```

data to be post using JavaScript and PSOT method to test.php

example

```
input
    test.php / post data : count=5
output
    01234
```

I want JavaScript to get me the output (01234) after posting (count=5) to (test.php) located in external server (www.domaine.com)

I basically develop in C# but as I'm obliged to do a cross-platform mobile app I switched to JavaScript (won't use Xamarin) for C# I was able to do everything using WebBrowser but not anymore in JavaScript, isn't there any object equivalent to WebBrowser in .NET ?

I need it for a mobile app that will load data from GPS Tracking website, API returns data in both XML and JSON

note : I don't have access to the external server

Comment: Are you asking how to do an ajax request?

Comment: I'm asking how to do this I want an easy detailed how-to :)

Answer (score 2):

Here I'll give you a pretty good example of how these things are usually managed.
Still, it's up to you and your programming experience to grasp the meaning of it.

html and js example:

```
<form action="" id="formId" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label for="inputNumber">Input something: </label>
    <input type="number" id="inputNumber" name="count"></input>
</form>
<span id="submit">Submit</span>

<script>
var getPhpResponse = function( data ) {
    console.log("manage php response HERE");
}

$("#submit").click(function(){
    $("#formId").submit();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#formId").bind("submit", function (event)
        {
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                data: $("#formId").serialize(),
                success: function(data, textStatus) {
                    getPhpResponse( data )
                },
                type:"POST",
                url:"name/and/location/of/php/file.php"
            });
            return false;
        });
});
</script>
```

file.php example:

```
<?php
$x = $_POST['count'];
echo '{"response":"';
for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++)
{
    echo $i;
}
echo '"}';
```

Poxriptum:

1. There should be further input validation, one can't trust the `type="number"` just yet.
2. That the submit button is a `span` instead of an `input` is a personal choice that makes difference just for styling purposes.
3. You should read up on AJAX and JSON.
4. Consider using a PHP framework, such as [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/); it may serve you well.
5. This answer assumes you *have access* to the server. If you don't, then you should be reading the API documentation instead of asking questions on SO without even detailing which API you are talking about.

Edit:

Here is the $less version.

```
<form action="" id="formId" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label for="inputNumber">Input something: </label>
    <input type="number" id="inputNumber" name="count"></input>
</form>
<span id="submit">Submit</span>

<script>
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function () {
    var url = 'name/and/location/of/php/file.php';
    var userInput = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("inputNumber").value);
    var data = "count=" + userInput;
    makeRequest( data, url );
};

var getPhpResponse = function( data ) {
    console.log("manage php response HERE");
    console.log(data);
    parsed = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(parsed);
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

var makeRequest = function( data, url ) {
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    xhr.send(data);
};

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if ( xhr.readyState == 4 )
    {
        if ( xhr.status == 200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1 )
        {
            getPhpResponse(xhr.responseText);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Manage error here");
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Who said jQuery was available?

Comment: Holy! You're right... I'll add the jQuery-less version in a minute.